# Sharepoint secured folder visible by direct url

Tags: security, sharepoint

I have a folder in a Sharepoint Foundation 2010 document library with unique permissions so only a specific group of users can access.
The folder is created only in some cases and it's important that other users can't know when the folder exists or not.
But if a user with no access permissions types the direct url doesn't get an error, but a page showing an empty folder. 
It's good that he can't see the content, but it's not good that he can know that the folder is there.
Is it a Sharepoint security bug?

[EDIT]
I made a test on Sharepoint 2007. Users with no access on a folder get a Access Denied Error if they type the direct url. 
I think the behavior on Sharepoint 2010 is a real bug.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a bug. This is how it has always worked.

Comment: But it is not the typical behavior of Sharepoint security. If a user can't access a list item and type the direct url he gets an "item not found error".